# How does one calculate 2 ^ -18 using GMP?

Tags: c, gmp

I've just discovered, to my embarrassment, that feeding negative exponents to `mpz_pow_ui` doesn't work very well. ("The manual does say unsigned long, you know.") For the other `mpz_pow` functions, the manual uses concepts I don't understand. For example "*base*^*exp* mod *mod*" in the following:

```
void mpz_powm (mpz_t rop, mpz_t base, mpz_t exp, mpz_t mod) 
void mpz_powm_ui (mpz_t rop, mpz_t base, unsigned long int exp, mpz_t mod)
Set _rop_ to _base_^_exp_ mod _mod_.
Negative exp is supported if an inverse base-1 mod mod exists (see mpz_invert in Section 5.9 [Number Theoretic Functions], page 35). If an inverse doesn’t exist then a divide by zero is raised.
```

In the following code, what do I have to change to make it able to handle negative exponents?

```
#define Z(x) mpz_t x; mpz_init( x );

BSTR __stdcall IBIGPOWER(BSTR p1, long p2 ) {
    USES_CONVERSION;

    Z(n1);
    Z(res);

    LPSTR sNum1 = W2A( p1 );

    mpz_set_str( n1, sNum1, 10 );

    mpz_pow_ui( res, n1, p2 );

    char * buff =  (char *) _alloca( mpz_sizeinbase( res, 10 ) + 2 );

    mpz_get_str(buff, 10, res);

    BSTR bResult = _com_util::ConvertStringToBSTR( buff );
    return bResult;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `mpz_t` data type can only store integers, and 2<sup>-18</sup> is not an integer.  To calculate that, you'll have to use the floating-point type [`mpf_t`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Floating_002dpoint-Functions.html#Floating_002dpoint-Functions) or the rational number type [`mpq_t`](http://gmplib.org/manual/Rational-Number-Functions.html#Rational-Number-Functions).

Comment: Now that is a good point. Sigh: too little sleep, and too little thinking it through.

Answer (score 10):

I won't cut the code for you but I will make you aware that:

`2-n = 1/2n`

So you can just pass the positive exponent then divide 1 by that number (and choose a non-integer type like `mpf_t` - the `mpz_t` type is integral so cannot represent real numbers like `2-18`).

Comment: LOL! I'm quivering, I am quivering.

Comment: Easier to read, and easier to type, would be: <h2>2<sup>-n</sup> = 1 / 2<sup>n</sup></h2>

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about GMP but:

```
2 ^ -18
```

is equivalent to:

```
1 / (2 ^ 18)
```

So why not write a function that handles negative exponents in this way?

Answer (score 2):

> Negative exp is supported if an
>   inverse base-1 mod mod exists (see
>   mpz_invert in Section 5.9 [Number
>   Theoretic Functions], page 35). If an
>   inverse doesn’t exist then a divide by
>   zero is raised.

If you're talking about that, that's involves number theory. Division, or more precisely inverse of multplication, only exists on certain conditions. I don't exactly remember the rules, but basically it's saying that the division operation won't work if *base-1* mod *mod* doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do depends on what you want to happen with the bits that will lost in the operation. Since you are dealing with integers, raising to a negative power implies division (well, reciprocation), but GMP offers several forms of [division](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Division.html#Integer-Division).